# Java spring ressources not being updated when server deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, ubuntu, tomcat

I am working on a spring web application using eclipse. For the longest time everything was working fine just until recently I have been having this weird problem. The problem is that when I modify a cs or js file and deploy the server, the source files sent to the browser stays the same as before the modification was made. The only way that I am able to update these files is by rebooting the computer. How can I fix this?

I have tried:
**maven update,**
**clean project,**
**clean tomcat directory,**
**clean tomcat,**
**reinstalling eclipse**

note: I am using eclipse neon on linux ubuntu and tomcat 8 for the server

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In general, Browser caches css or js files, so you need to delete them from Browser > Delete History to get the css or js file changes reflected.**

Comment: or just try Ctrl + F5

Comment: Thanks very much : )